# Typescript: describe a function using an interface without converting function to a const

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following interface:

```
interface MyFunctionType {
  (text: string): string;
};
```

And the following function:

```
function myFunction(text) {
  const newText = "new" + text;
  return newText;
}
```

How do I define `myFunction` as being `MyFunctionType`?

I have previously been using arrow functions to get over this hurdle, such as:

```
const myFunction: MyFunctionType = (text) => {
  const newText = "new" + text;
  return newText;
}
```

Which works fine, however I'd prefer to use normal functions instead of arrow functions for clarity. I'd prefer not to inline the types, such as:

```
function myFunction(text: string): string {
  const newText = "new" + text;
  return newText;
}
```

How can I do this?

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
function myFunction(text): MyFunctionType {
  const newText = "new" + text;
  return newText;
}

function myFunction<MyFunctionType>(text) {
  const newText = "new" + text;
  return newText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `let` - you are enforcing the type of the variable to hold the function.

The [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) manual has a nice example:

```
interface SearchFunc {
   (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
}

let mySearch: SearchFunc; 
mySearch = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    let result = source.search(subString);
    return result > -1; 
}
```

You define a function interface as you did, and then you can use `let` to declare the function type.

And without `let`, you again enforce the type on the variable rather than the function object:

```
var mySearch: SearchFunc = function(source: string, subString: string) {
    let result = source.search(subString);
    return result > -1; 
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you. Unfortunately this is even less clear than simply using arrow functions, so it seems like my best option is just to stick with arrow functions for everything.

Comment: @Jake added another option!